# postgresql rails 4 issue with record_changed? is defined by Active Record

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting an error :   `record_changed? is defined by Active Record`

could not find any info on this in documentation or online,
what is causing this?

Comment: The problem occurs in the line:

= simple_form_for(@game, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|

Comment: Had the same problem with mysql but answer by @Bluntelk was right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is - you have a field called "record" in your table. Active Record is automatically trying to create a field called "record_changed?" to see if the field has changed, but has already created this method to see if the row has changed.